# How can I add counted elements in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple little program which should count the number of common occurring characters in two strings. I have the below code, but I am stuck on returning the final expression.

I've added a few `print` statements in there to see what is going on during the process. I am getting each character correctly counting but i'm not sure how I can total these and output a final 'total count' of all the common character occurrences. At the moment it is just returning the final character count of the first string

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
count = 0
totalcount = 0
for c in text1:
    print c 
    # see if its in `text2`
    if c in text2:
        count = text2.count(c)
        totalcount = count      ----> This line is incorrect
    print totalcount
return totalcount
```

**EDIT:** The total count needs to display the aggregate total of each character.
eg. text1 = ban, text2 = banana

b = 1
a = 3

n = 2
totalcount = 6

Comment: `totalcount = totalcount + count`?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be just `totalcount += 1`

Answer (score 0):

`text2.count()` returns the number of characters in the string, assuming text2 is of type string.

What you really want is that with each common element found, you add 1 to your counter like so:

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
totalcount = 0
for c in text1:
    print c 
    # see if its in `text2`
    if c in text2:
        totalcount += 1
    print totalcount
return totalcount
```